# How to drop all lldp packets on a specific port using IPTables?

Tags: iptables, netfilter

I have lldp packets sent on a specific port (6633) and i need to drop only and only if they are lldp packets, because i have another traffic that cant be dropped, so i can't just drop all traffic on the port. Is this possible? If its not possible, there's any other way to do that?

Comment: lldp is it's own layer 2 protocol and doesn't go to a "port" (AFAIK) so it does not make sense to filter lldp on a specific port (?!)

Comment: Being puzzled by this (LLDP *and* a port), I stumbled on this: https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/openflowplugin/en/latest/users/operation.html#enable-controller-tls  and https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/openflowplugin/en/latest/users/operation.html#openflow-topology . So I guess 1/ it's about openvswitch 2/ one connects to the control plane with 6633/tcp (tls), uses a REST API to do operations, and then some bridge traffic using LLDP happens because of this. OP should clarify the whole setup and give a concrete reason needed to do whatever has to be done. 6633/tcp is TLS encrypted